# How to really disable ctrl+shift+arrow keys in Windows Terminal Preview?

Tags: windows-terminal

Everytime I try to use `ctrl-shift-up` or `ctrl-shift-down` inside of the new windows terminal preview, it scrolls the terminal view up or down. I tried going into the `profiles.json` file and set the `"command" : "scrollDown"` and `"command" : "scrollUp"` to `"unbound"` but it has no effect.

If I try to bind `scollUp` to something else, let's say `ctrl+alt+b`, then it correctly adds the keybind to the command. It seems like there's a default windows keybinding that is set to scroll the terminal view up and down using `ctrl+shift+arrows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you found the answer, but I was looking for this too. Found the below in a microsfot devblog that works currently:

> If there is a default key binding included in the defaults.json file
>   that you would like to free up, you can set that key binding to null
>   in your profiles.json.
>
> ```
> {
> "command": null, "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"]
> }
> ```

Link to full article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1910-release/

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u0000" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u0000" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },
```

so when you press the keys, it replaces the undesirable command with sending a null character to the input (that, of course, does nothing lol)